# CMOS source follower with 2 in series

Tags: mosfet, cmos, small-signal, source-follower

I am really struggling with where to start to analyse this. 
Using the Shichman Hodges Model and the small signal equivalent circuit, the voltage gain can be equation can be seen to be vo = -gmvgsr0. But how can two be joined together? I have looked online and can not find anything similar which has explanation.

Thank you for your help.

[image: Question]

Here is my attempt at trying to analyse the first circuit:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8aEF.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yvbl.jpg[image]

Comment: You have three N-channel and three P-channel source followers. The only difference within each group is the nature of the load. Start by drawing the "load line" for each kind of load.

Comment: @KingDuken yes, how can you calculate how one affects another. I sort of understand that when the MOSFET gate is connected to its drain, then it will act as a diode. Maybe that is supposed to simplify the analysis.

Comment: @DaveTweed Not too sure how to look at it with the load line? thought that would be the same for any mosfet? I have added my small signal analysis attempt above?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to draw the small signal equivalents of each of them. After some practice, intuition will help to tackle them. I have attached the picutres of my worksheet for the first three cases (circuits 1,2,3). The others can be found similarly. I have kept the variables as gm and gds with suffixes 1 or 2 indicating the mosfet numbers. They can suitably substituted using the variables Kn,Kp, W,L respectively.

[image]

[image]

[image]